# performance of mysql +php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql driven application where in all data comes from mysql and display it using php.

when designing the DB what all precautions must be taken so that mysql gives best performance.

i had a small doubt . I have text column in my form , and i dono how much length data will be entered . So instead of varchar(255) if i create it as varchar(2000) does it effects the performance ?

Comment: I believe *what all* should be read *which*, and a question mark replacing the period at the end.

Comment: ~ There's a concept called "Premature Optimization" ... The advice goes like this: "Write the application well, and make sure the principles are sound. It will scale reasonably well, and run in a reasonable time. Once the application is written well, and is complete, then scaling, or performance, can be improved. Doing it in any other order is Premature Optimization." It's a bad thing. Additionally, "Profile Profile Profile" and then you can know what is not working as well as it may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varchar takes the number of bytes of the data + length prefix regardless of the length define

eg.

'xyz' will take 4 bytes, 3 bytes for the data and 1 or 2 bytes will be added for length prefix, A column uses 1 byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes. In this case 1 byte will add up since data require less than 255 bytes.

So go on buddy affect on the performance is negligible, that's the beauty of VARCHAR.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. Varchars define a maximum length. They use as much or as little space (plus a small fixed overhead) as the data they contain.

The only thing you may need to consider is the total row length and this varies depending on what storage engine you use. See [13.2.14. Restrictions on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> The maximum row length, except for
>   variable-length columns (VARBINARY,
>   VARCHAR, BLOB and TEXT), is slightly
>   less than half of a database page.
>   That is, the maximum row length is
>   about 8000 bytes. LONGBLOB and
>   LONGTEXT columns must be less than
>   4GB, and the total row length,
>   including BLOB and TEXT columns, must
>   be less than 4GB.
>
> If a row is less than half a page
>   long, all of it is stored locally
>   within the page. If it exceeds half a
>   page, variable-length columns are
>   chosen for external off-page storage
>   until the row fits within half a page,
>   as described in Section 13.2.11.2,
>   “File Space Management”.

and [10.5. Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

> The maximum size of a row in a MyISAM
>   table is 65,535 bytes. This figure
>   excludes BLOB or TEXT columns, which
>   contribute only 9 to 12 bytes toward
>   this size.

Comment: I'd add something about sort overhead but otherwise upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

> So instead of varchar(255) if i create it as varchar(2000) does it effects the performance ?

It rather depends. While the system can accomodate this, consider the following table:

```
 create table example (
    id int NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    smallstr VARCHAR(20),
    anumber mediumint(6) DEFAULT 0,
    bigstr (2000)
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    KEY lookup (anumber, smallstr)
 )
```

As others have said, the size of each row will vary - lets say there's an average of 1kbytes, and a million rows. But if your queries are mostly NOT looking at that big varchar field, then the structure is very inefficient - it still has to be read off the disk each time, even though it never gets to the result set. So you need to read at least a gigabyte of data. But if you split this:

```
 create table example2 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    smallstr VARCHAR(20),
    anumber mediumint(6) DEFAULT 0
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    KEY lookup (anumber, smallstr)
 );   
 create table example2_sub (
   ex2_id int NOT NULL,
   bigstr (2000)
   PRIMARY_KEY (ex2_id)
 );
```

The average row size would drop to around 25 bytes - i.e. 1/40th of that using a consolidated table. OTOH, when you do need to perform a bulk query on example2 and example2_sub it will be slower than the consolidated table (I would expect that it would slow down by something of the order of 30% - but I've not tested it).

(note that you should restrict the size of HTML input fields to the corresponding database attributes wherever possible).

HTH

C.